# CAShapeLayer cutout in UIView

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cashapelayer

My goal is to create a pretty opaque background with a clear rounded rect inset

```
    let shape = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shape, cornerRadius: 16).cgPath
    maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

    let background = UIView()
    background.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
    view.addSubview(background)
    constrain(background) {
        $0.edges == $0.superview!.edges
    }

    background.layer.addSublayer(maskLayer)
//        background.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

When I uncomment `background.layer.mask = maskLayer`, the view is totally clear. When I have it commented out, I see the semi-opaque background color but no mask cutout

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a playground that I think implements your intended effect (minus `.edges` and `constrain` - that appear to be your own extensions).

a) used a red background instead of black with alpha (just to make the effect stand out)

b) set `maskLayer.backgroundColor` instead of `maskLayer.fillColor`

Adding the maskLayer as another layer to `uiview` is superfluous (as indicated by @Ken) but seems to do no harm.

```
    import UIKit
    import PlaygroundSupport


    let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200)

    let uiview = UIView(frame: bounds)
    uiview.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.8)

    PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = uiview

    let shape = CGRect(x: 100, y: 50, width: 200, height: 100)


    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shape, cornerRadius: 16).cgPath
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    uiview.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

[image of clear inset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ5fz.png)

On the other hand, if you intended a picture frame / colored-envelope-with-transparent-window effect like below, then see [gist](https://gist.github.com/mpdroid/fd8dbeabf8dc874e78937db0273bf4bc)

[image of picture frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqbLx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your mask Layer has no size.
Add this line `maskLayer.frame = shape`

and you don't need `background.layer.addSublayer(maskLayer)`