# How to change color only a fraction of the total in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, camera, qr-code

I'm doing a QR code scan. I use `UIView` to change the background color of the screen to translucent color. However, I want to make the background color of the place that scans the QR code transparent. What should I do?

```swift
class QRcodeScannerViewController : UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var qrcodeView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var header: UINavigationBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var flash: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var qrcodeScanArea: UIImageView!
                   var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.qrcodeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(flash)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(header)
        header.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        header.isTranslucent = true
        header.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        header.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

### Current My QRcode ScanView

[image: qr]

### Here's the view I want:

[image]

### I don't know which part I reverse, but only the color I want is black and the rest is transparent.

```swift
        view.addSubview(qrcodeView)
        let shape = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shape, cornerRadius: 0).cgPath
        maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        maskLayer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd
        qrcodeView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

[image]

### I made and applied the class by referring to the answers below. But it doesn't work for me.

```swift
let focusview = FocusView.init(frame: qrcodeView.frame)
focusview.areaBackground = UIColor.black
view.addSubview(focusview)
```

[image]

Comment: [CAShapeLayer cutout in UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47722301/cashapelayer-cutout-in-uiview); [How to mask one UIView using another UIView](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-mask-one-uiview-using-another-uiview)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Would you mind looking at my revised question?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar ... actually pretty much the same thing, some time ago.

I've dug out the code I used and have posted it here for your reference

```
fileprivate let focusSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 218, height: 150)
fileprivate let focusCornerRadius: CGFloat = 10.0

class FocusView: UIView {

    var areaBackground: UIColor? {
        set {
            maskedFocusView.backgroundColor = newValue
        }

        get {
            return maskedFocusView.backgroundColor
        }
    }

    fileprivate let maskedFocusView: MaskedFocusView = {
        return MaskedFocusView()
    }()

    let focusView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        view.layer.borderWidth = 2
        view.layer.cornerRadius = focusCornerRadius
//      view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
//      view.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
//      view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9
//      view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return view
    }()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(maskedFocusView)
        addSubview(focusView)
        setupFocusViewConstraints()
        setupMaskedFocusViewConstraints()
    }

    func setupFocusViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
            focusView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            focusView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor)
        )

        let regularFocusViewConstraints = [
            focusView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: focusSize.width),
            focusView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: focusSize.height)
        ]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(regularFocusViewConstraints)
    }

    func setupMaskedFocusViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
            maskedFocusView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            maskedFocusView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            maskedFocusView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            maskedFocusView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            maskedFocusView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            maskedFocusView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        )
    }

}

// MARK: - Masked focus view

fileprivate class MaskedFocusView: UIView {

    let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

        maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        layer.mask = maskLayer

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let width = bounds.width
        let height = bounds.height

        let x = (width - focusSize.width) / 2
        let y = (height - focusSize.height) / 2

        let focusRect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: focusSize.width, height: focusSize.height)
        let fullRect = CGRect(origin: bounds.origin, size: bounds.size)

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addPath(UIBezierPath(rect: fullRect).cgPath)
        path.addPath(UIBezierPath(roundedRect: focusRect, cornerRadius: focusCornerRadius).reversing().cgPath)

        maskLayer.path = path
        maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
    }

}

// MARK: - Layout constraints extension

extension NSLayoutConstraint {
  /// A helper function to activate layout constraints.
  static func activate(_ constraints: NSLayoutConstraint? ...) {
    for case let constraint in constraints {
      guard let constraint = constraint else {
        continue
      }

      (constraint.firstItem as? UIView)?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      constraint.isActive = true
    }
  }
}

extension Array where Element: NSLayoutConstraint {
  func activate() {
    forEach {
      if !$0.isActive {
        $0.isActive = true
      }
    }
  }

  func deactivate() {
    forEach {
      if $0.isActive {
        $0.isActive = false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing me with good materials. How do I use the class I created when I try to use it?

Comment: This is just a `UIView`, so you can just add it to you existing view

Comment: I don't think I understand this class very well. It doesn't work for me. I'm sorry, but could you please look at the corrected My question?